# How To Upload Pdf In Php

Tags: php

I sucessfully uploaded a PDF file but I'm not able to upload to particular named uploads:

Before clicking on the upload button I'm getting notices:

```
Notice: Undefined index: myFile in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo3.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo3.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: myFile in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo3.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: myFile in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo3.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: uploads_dir in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo3.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: uploads_dir in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo3.php on line 15


           /*After Clicking on Upload Button*/

1.)Notice:Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_DIR - assumed 'UPLOAD_DIR' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo.php on line 20                                                                           
2.)Notice: Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_DIR - assumed 'UPLOAD_DIR' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo.php on line 27
3.)Notice: Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_DIR - assumed 'UPLOAD_DIR' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF UPLOAD DEMO\Upload_PDF_Demo.php on line 34
```

Here's my code

```
<?php

         define("uploads","./");

        //$uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
         $_FILES["myFile"]["error"];
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
        {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"];
        echo "".$tmp_name;
        $name = $_FILES["myFile"]["name"];
        echo "".$name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir."/".$name, $uploads_dir);
        echo "".$tmp_name;
        }
         echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
        <form action="Upload_PDF_Demo.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
```

Notices Before Clicking On Upload Button
[image: Notices Before Clicking On Upload Button]

Notices After Clicking On Upload Button
[image: Notices After Clicking On Upload Button]

OUTPUT of My Program
[image: OUTPUT of My Program]

Comment: We would need to see the HTML you use for the `<form...` but basically it looks like you are using the wrong names for almost everything. I suggest you start by reading [the PHP manual on File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 1):

you have to check if there is a file in request before

```
if (!empty($_FILES['myFile']['name'])) {
     define("uploads","./");

        //$uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
         $_FILES["myFile"]["error"];
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
        {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"];
        echo "".$tmp_name;
        $name = $_FILES["myFile"]["name"];
        echo "".$name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir."/".$name, $uploads_dir);
        echo "".$tmp_name;
        }
         echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}


<form action="Upload_PDF_Demo.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```